# Тире с пробелами или дефис? Кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, дефис-тире

Какой знак (тире с пробелами /дефис) должен быть в сочетаниях: *баланс семья-работа / соотношение семья-работа*? Нужно ли закавычивать "семья-работа"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таких сочетаниях следует ставить **тире** (с пробелами), кавычки не требуются:

*баланс семья — работа*,
*соотношение семья — работа*.

[**Тире в функции соединения**](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=59) (Справочник под ред. Лопатина)

> Тире ставится... между нарицательными именами существительными, сочетание которых выполняет определительную функцию при имени существительном: *Система **человек — машина**; Отношения **учитель — ученик**; Проблема **рыночные отношения — социальная справедливость***. Число сочетающихся имен может быть и больше двух: *Проблема **производство — человек — природа***...

*То, о чем я говорю, сказывается, конечно, и на традиционной связи **учитель ― ученик***... [А. Караулов, М. К. Мамардашвили, Ю. Сенокосов. Если осмелиться быть... // «Родник», 1989]

В печати можно встретить разное оформление подобных пар. **Кавычки** не редкость, их использование не противоречит правилам и графически выделяет сочетание "связанных" слов:

*На материале истории сотрудничества А. Н. Леонтьева с Л. С. Выготским рассмотрена диада **«учитель ― ученик»** в науке.* [Б. С. Братусь. Леонтьевские основания смысловых концепций личности // «Вопросы психологии», 2004.08.10]

*Фантастика изучает не только отношения **«человек ― человек»**, но и отношения **«человек — общество»**, **«человек ― наука»***. [Не стало Кира Булычева ― умер Игорь Можейко // «Знание ― сила», 2003]